# How to determine "Number" data type from arbitrary "String" inputs

Tags: java, string, numbers, jax-rs, integer-arithmetic

I have tried to search a lot about it but couldn't come to a concrete solution.

I am developing a rest service (using Jax-RS) for which 3 Number inputs are provided, but for each input, the actual data type is unknown at compile time. e.g; "num1" can be any Number i.e. int, long, float or double etc, similarly "num2" and "num3".

```
@GET
@Path("func/{num1}/{num2}/{num3}")
public String function (@PathParam("num1") String num1, @PathParam("num2") String num2, @PathParam("num3") String num3) { 

// Determine the data type of "num1", "num2" and "num3"
// Perform any arithmetic operation on "num1", "num2" and "num3" and return the result;

}
```

How can I determine the data type of each input to perform any computation?

Currently, I checking the type by using series of Wrapper.parseXXX methods as in the following code but this approach doesn't seem right.

```
private Boolean isByte(String s) {
    try  {
        Byte.parseByte(s);
        return true;

    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
private Boolean isInt(String s) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(s);
        return true;

    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
private Boolean isLong(String s) {
    try {
        Long.parseLong(s);
        return true;

    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
private Boolean isStrFloat(String str) {
    try {
        Float.parseFloat(str);
        return true;

    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
private Boolean isStrDouble(String str) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(str);
        return true;

    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or should I use BigInteger/BigDecimal for all of the inputs?

Comment: You should define your API with a certain expected number format.  If a user deviates from this, be ready to catch an exception.  Keep in mind someone could pass text in addition to the wrong number format.

Comment: Use org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils.isParsable

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't really need to detect the smallest number type possible and just using `Double` will probably be fine. If the incoming parameter happens to be byte sized, it will parse without any problem:

```
Double.parseDouble(str);
```

But you can also use `java.text.NumberFormat` to parse any incoming number:

```
Number num = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(myNumber);
```

Check the javadoc of [Numberformat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) for all the options.

Answer (score 0):

Using JAX-RS, you can force matching of this method for numbers only.

The method would look like this then:

```
@GET
@Path("func/{num1: [0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+){0,1}}/{num2: [0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+){0,1}}/{num3: [0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+){0,1}}")
public String function (@PathParam("num1") Double num1, @PathParam("num2") Double num2, @PathParam("num3") Double num3) {
}
```

If numbers are not what you'd expect, then the client will be answered a `404 Not Found`

Note how I set the type of the parameters to `Double`. the JAX-RS specification states that all types with a `valueOf(String)` method can be used in method arguments. Since we force the type of parameters, we can safely convert to Double here.